# Nginx: How to host 2 different websites on same server?

Tags: nginx

Here's what I have in my /etc/nginx/sites-available/ folder

allverse.co

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name allverse.co www.allverse.co;
    root /var/www/allverse;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
```

jademgr.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jademgr.com www.jademgr.com;
    root /var/www/jademgr;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5010;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
```

I have them running under supervisor.

```
[program:jademgr]
command=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/jademgr/jademgr.dll
directory=/var/www/jademgr/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/jademgr.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/jademgr.out.log
environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
user=www-data
stopsignal=INT
```

allverse

```
[program:allverse]
command=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/allverse/allverse.dll
directory=/var/www/allverse/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/allverse.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/allverse.out.log
environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
user=www-data
stopsignal=INT
```

I have allverse set to run on port 5000 and jademgr set to run on port 5010. What am I doing wrong? When I start both sites they both point to the same jademgr site.

Thanks.

Comment: if on localhost and you hit the different local ports do they both work?

Comment: Did you do a nginx reload after?

Comment: @ShawnC. I just got the ports right, but now when I log into one site it's displaying information from the other site info. When I clear the cache both sites seem to be ok. I'm running angular so I'm guessing some JS is loading and being used for both sites somehow. I'll see if I can use different names for the JS now I suppose to solve this issue.